# MTLS in Web API, .Net framework 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-framework-version, mtls

I want to implement MTLS in my Web APIs. The target framework is 4.6.1. All the articles I get are for .Net Core.
The articles did help me understand the concept, but I am not sure how to write it down in C# code.

I tried adding webhooks, but got nowhere with it.